# Could not find function "%^%"

Tags: r

I'm running an [example](https://rpubs.com/JanpuHou/326048) about Markov Chain. Everything is working so far except for this code produces an error:

```
ra2 <- ra %^% 2
```

> Error in ra %^% 2 : could not find function "%^%"

Magrittr package doesn't include the above operator. Any feedback?

Comment: This is described in the context : `the efficient operator %^% from the expm package is used to raise the Oz matrix to the third power.`

Comment: The code in this example includes the required `library` calls. Run them.

Answer (score 3):

That is the efficient operator `%^%` from [package expm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expm/expm.pdf). It computes the k-th power of a matrix. Therefore you need to load or install the `expm` package first.